# minimize the perimeter of a triangle generated by three generally positioned lines in 3-dimensional space

Tags: geometry, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider three generally positioned lines in 3-dimensional space (i.e. they are pairwise disjoint and not mutually parallel). Let these three lines be$L_1, L_2$ and $L_3$.

Now, if we fix any three points $P_1; P_2; P_3$ from the lines $L_1;L_2;L_3$ respectively, then we will have a triangle formed by $P_1; P_2; P_3$.

The question is: Can we find $P_1; P_2; P_3$ so as to minimize the perimeter of the triangle (i.e. $\left\lVert P_1 - P_2 \right\rVert + \left\lVert P_2 - P_3\right\rVert + \left\lVert P_1 - P_3\right\rVert$)

1. Show that an optimal solution ($P_1^*, P_2^*, P_3^*$) exists which minimizes the function $\left\lVert P_1 - P_2 \right\rVert + \left\lVert P_2 - P_3\right\rVert + \left\lVert P_1 - P_3\right\rVert$, and the optimal solution is actually unique.
2. Any point $P_i$ along $L_i$ can be parameterized by $P_i(t) = c_i +td_i$ where $c_i$ is a given point on $L_i$ and $d_i$ is the direction of $L_i, i = 1; 2; 3$. Formulate our optimization problem.
3. Prove: In the optimal position, the angle between $ [ P_i^* ; P_j^* ]$ and $L_i$, and the angle between $[P_i^* ; P_j^* ]$ and $L_j$ must be equal, where $1 \leq i \neq j \leq 3$.

---

Actually I have no idea about question 1 and 3, any possible direction or related materials would be helpful.

As for question 2), I think the optimization problem should be:

$$\min_{t_1, t_2, t_3} \left\lVert P_1(t_1) - P_2(t_2) \right\rVert + \left\lVert P_2(t_2) - P_3(t_3)\right\rVert + \left\lVert P_1(t_1) - P_3(t_3)\right\rVert$$

$$s.t. P_i(t_i) = c_i + t_id_i, \forall i \in \{1,2, 3\}$$
$$t_i \in \mathbb{R}, \forall i \in \{1,2, 3\}$$

---

Reedit:

For question 1), can we say $P_i$ is contiuous since it's along line $L_i, \forall i \in \{1, 2, 3\}$. Then, if we want to min L2 norm $\left\lVert P_1 - P_2 \right\rVert^2 + \left\lVert P_2 - P_3\right\rVert^2 + \left\lVert P_1 - P_3\right\rVert^2$, we can find it is a strictly convex, hence we can say optimal solution exists and is unique.

For question 3), if we denote the angle between $ [ P_i^* ; P_j^* ]$ and $L_i$ as $\theta_i$ and the angle between $ [ P_i^* ; P_j^* ]$ and $L_j$ as $\theta_j$, actually we want to show

$$\mid cos(\theta_i)\mid = \frac{\mid (P_i(t_i^*) - P_j(t_j^*))^Td_i \mid}{\left\lVert P_i(t_i^*) - P_j(t_j^*) \right\rVert \left\lVert d_i\right\rVert} = \mid cos(\theta_j) \mid = \frac{\mid (P_i(t_i^*) - P_j(t_j^*))^Td_j \mid}{\left\lVert P_i(t_i^*) - P_j(t_j^*) \right\rVert \left\lVert d_j\right\rVert}, $$
which is equivalent to $\frac{\mid (P_i(t_i^*) - P_j(t_j^*))^Td_i \mid}{\mid (P_i(t_i^*) - P_j(t_j^*))^Td_j \mid} = \frac{\left\lVert d_i\right\rVert}{\left\lVert d_j\right\rVert}$.

The optimality conditions for 2) are

$$(P_1(t_1^*) - P_2(t_2^*))^Td_1 + (P_1(t_1^*) - P_3(t_3^*))^Td_1 = 0$$
$$(P_2(t_2^*) - P_3(t_3^*))^Td_2 + (P_2(t_2^*) - P_1(t_1^*))^Td_2 = 0$$
$$(P_2(t_2^*) - P_3(t_3^*))^Td_3 + (P_1(t_1^*) - P_3(t_3^*))^Td_3 = 0$$

I do not know what to do next then or if there is any condition that I did not find.

Comment: What methods are you supposed to use to solve the optimization problem? Will it suffice to recall $||x||=\sqrt{x^2}$ and equate partial derivatives wrt $t_i$ to $0$? Btw, 2) answer looks fine to me.

Comment: It’s not given but I think it makes sense for me to use L2 norm.

Comment: Okay, but the derivatives expressions will be really heavy to solve by hand. Hence the question about methods is.